# What's the meaning of "dramatic" in this definition of drama?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sense 5 of *drama* from [AHDE](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/drama) is:

> The quality or condition of being dramatic: *a summit meeting full of drama.*

What does *dramatic* mean in this definition? Does it mean *[greatly affecting people's emotions](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/dramatic)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume  “a summit meeting full of drama” is unlikely to be one that greatly affects people's emotions, but rather one that contains  “theatrical, scenic, stagy, histrionic or melodramatic” goings-on.  (These adjectives express [connotations of *dramatic*](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/dramatic).)  Also see [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dramatic#dramatic_10)'s sense 4 of *dramatic*: “dramatic behavior is done to impress other people”.  That is, dramatic posturing (rather than emotional drama) is likely to occur in a summit meeting.